# Connecting neo4j database from Neo4j webadmin pane

Tags: neo4j

I have created neo4j nodes and relationships from java code , i am trying to use Neo4j webadmin panel to display them as a graph.
I have changed server config property "`org.neo4j.server.database.location`" to point to the DB folder i have created from java program.
Is there any other changes i need to do in order to view the nodes and relationships? how to achieve the same?

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your java program is shut down as it's not possible to access a graph.db directory more multiple Neo4j instances (1 server and 1 embedded in your example) at the same time.

Aside from this make sure you're using the same version.